# Drop cache job with certain condition gives error in crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I'm trying to apply a cronjob to drop cache that checks for a certain condition every minute and if the condition applies then it executes, also I don't want jobs to overlap if it takes longer than a minute so i'm using flock with it. The job is like below:

```
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/cachedrop.lock -c "if (( $(free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print ($3/$2) * 1000000}') > 34000 )) && (( $(free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print (($3+$6)/$2) * 1000000}') > 34000 )); then sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; fi"
```

The cron works, there is no syntax error whatsoever. When i run the command from cli it works fine. However as a cron job i receive this email on my /var/mail:

```
/bin/sh: 1: 194155: not found
```

The "194155"  is the output of the first fuction. It changes according to the ram use percentage. I am experiencing this problem in Ubuntu and Debian machines. I also tried to separate the functions to see what happens but the problem persists.

Just to test out i also tried a cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/ping.lock -c "timeout 300 ping 8.8.8.8"
```

It works fine, no errors no overlapping. Lock file works as expected.

Wondering if I made a mistake in the command tried the same cronjob in a centos machine as well and it works like a charm there. Please help me understand this problem i really need to make this work.

Comment: When a script runs ok in a terminal but not under cron it’s frequently because the environments are different. The solution can be to load the users environment at the start of the script. I think I’ve seen answers on here to that effect

Comment: This might help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that `flock` is using the value of `$SHELL` inherited from cron in order to execute the `flock -c 'command'`:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh

$ flock -n /tmp/mylock -c 'echo $0'
/usr/bin/zsh

$ SHELL=/bin/sh flock -n /tmp/mylock -c 'echo $0'
/bin/sh
```

In Ubuntu, cron uses `/bin/sh` by default, which (unlike `/bin/bash`) doesn't support your numerical expression ex.:

```
$ bash -c 'if ((2 > 1)); then echo Yes; fi'
Yes
```

whereas

```
$ sh -c 'if ((2 > 1)); then echo Yes; fi'
sh: 1: 2: not found
```

You can assign `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your crontab file, however since your command is somewhat complex I'd suggest creating a standalone bash script for it (with the appropriate `#!/bin/bash` shebang) and calling *that* as the `flock -c` command instead.